# UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field not marked as ignorable at Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@14ec141

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I am making rest web-services my code is:

```
@Path("/add")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addMembers(List<GroupMemberMap> groupMemberMaps){
    String message = "";            
    System.out.println("Inside addMembers of class "+this.toString());      
    try {
        DBConnection.insertMembers(groupMemberMaps);
        message = "Member(s) added";
        return Response.status(Status.CREATED)
                .entity(message)
                .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .build();
    } catch(SQLException sqle){
        System.out.println("addMembers catch sqle");
        message = "A problem occured while adding members : "+sqle.getMessage();
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity(message)
                .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .build();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Inside addMembers catch  "+e.getMessage());
        message = "A problem occured while adding members : "+e.getMessage();
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity(message)
                .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .build();
    }       
}
```

but when i call it with this Json :

```
[
{
    "userId":"3",
    "groupId":"4"
}
]
```

I'm getting following Exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "userId" (Class com.tazligen.model.GroupMemberMap), not marked as ignorable at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@14ec141; line: 2, column: 15] (through reference chain: com.tazligen.model.GroupMemberMap["userId"])

My GrouMemberMap model class is :

```
package com.tazligen.model;

@XmlRootElement
public class GroupMemberMap {

private String userId;
private String groupId;

public String getUserid() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserid(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getGroupId() {
    return groupId;
}
public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
}       }
```

I have tried another method just like this :

```
@Path("/membertest")
@POST   
public String test(List<User> members){
    return "Test subresource members working";
}
```

with json

```
[{
"userId":"3",
"userName":"John"}]
```

but this works alright :/

Need Someone help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can make following observations after looking at `GroupMemberMap` Class:

1. Constructor is missing.
2. Getter-Setter for the `UserId` is incorrect.

Also, you can add optional `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to ignore all other unknown fields.

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
package com.tazligen.model;

@XmlRootElement
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GroupMemberMap {

    @JsonProperty("userId")
    private String userId;
    @JsonProperty("groupId")
    private String groupId;

    /* Add Constructor */
    public GroupMemberMap() {}

    /* Corrected Name */
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    /* Corrected Name */
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }    
}
```

Comment: i have edited my question a bit in which u can see that i tried with a different model class but similar json pattern but that one works

Comment: Updated the solution. Please try now.

Comment: Your no 2 observation did the trick getter setter was wrong and the only reason why i ever missed it was because i had eclipse autogenerate it for me So i never thought it would be wrong so i never paid attension to that part .-_-
Damn you Eclipse . Thanks a ton sir :)

Comment: @Muhammad Your Welcome! :)

Comment: Solved my problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Just modify  userId and groupId `public`.** By default, Jackson works on public member variables.

I think JsonIgnoreProperties is not solution as it is used to ignore whatever it doesn't recognize.

```
public String userId;
public String groupId;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using lombok to generate getters and setters with @Getter and @Setter annotation. Now what solved a similar issue for me was converting data type of a field from primary java type boolean to Boolean. Lombok only generated a getter for it only if I used Boolean fieldName.

Answer (score -1):

above solution worked for me and I had string array inside json object .
I used JsonIgnore properties and replaced square brackets for the objects inside json object..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31455709)